# Cannot bound a NOT EXISTS clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with an append job I'm trying to automate on a weekly basis. We currently have two different databases on site. One is for our ERP and the other is for our HMI/SCADA system that we are building. I have linked the servers already and can query from the ERP database to pull a parts list; However I want this to update on a weekly basis as we randomly receive new part numbers and I don't want o be responsible for keeping up with any new part numbers, or changes to the child etc. The following query gives me the expected results, except when I run it each time it dumps all of the parts into the SCADA database each time:

```
INSERT INTO scada.dbo.Testing (ps_par, ps_comp)
    SELECT ps_par, ps_comp
    FROM OPENQUERY(ERP_QAD, 'SELECT ps_par, ps_comp FROM PUB.ps_mstr')
    WHERE [ps_par] LIKE 'PP%'
```

So I added the the "NOT EXISTS" to try and have it only bring in the "PP(Painted Parts)" that were not already in the table itself with the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO scada.dbo.Testing (ps_par, ps_comp)
    SELECT ps_par, ps_comp
    FROM OPENQUERY(ERP_QAD, 'SELECT ps_par, ps_comp FROM PUB.ps_mstr')
    WHERE [ps_par] LIKE 'PP%'
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ps_par 
                      FROM OPENQUERY(ERP_QAD, 'SELECT ps_par, ps_comp FROM PUB.ps_mstr')  
                      WHERE ERP.pub.ps_master.ps_par = scada.dbo.testing.ps_par)
```

This fails and I get this error message:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The multi-part identifier "ERP.pub.ps_master.ps_par" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The multi-part identifier "scada.dbo.testing.ps_par" could not be bound.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not great in SQL; so I feel like I'm close to the answer, just not sure how to write it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hard of hard to follow, but if you alias your open query, I think it should work.

```
INSERT INTO scada.dbo.Testing (ps_par,ps_comp)
select openQ.ps_par, openQ.ps_comp
from OPENQUERY(ERP_QAD,'Select ps_par, ps_comp FROM PUB.ps_mstr') openQ
where openQ.ps_par like 'PP%'and 
openQ.ps_par not in (select ps_par from scada.dbo.testing)
```

You may want to consider staging the results of the openquery into a temp table if you are going to use it later

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tempTable') is not null
drop table #tempTable

create table #tempTable (ps_par varchar(64), ps_mstr varchar(256))

insert into #tempTable
    SELECT ps_par, ps_comp
    FROM OPENQUERY(ERP_QAD, 'SELECT ps_par, ps_comp FROM PUB.ps_mstr')
    WHERE [ps_par] LIKE 'PP%'


INSERT INTO scada.dbo.Testing (ps_par, ps_comp)
    select t.*
    from #tempTable t
    where t.ps_ar not in (select ps_par from scada.dbo.Testing)
```

Comment: I'll give it a go - but should it say "AS openQ" for the alias?

Comment: You can, but it's not required @DaveHolt

Comment: I'm now just getting an error message on the scada.dbo.testing.ps_par part - Again I appreciate the help - Maybe to emphasize better on the edit here / I'm not sure how to alias the scada table as I'm not really...querying it? I think? haha

Comment: Also you said "You may want to consider staging the results of the openquery into a temp table so you don't have to make the remote call twice." I'm sorry man but that's past my skill set at the moment

Comment: @DaveHolt i edited the first query to use `not in` which simplifies this by not having to correlate the `not exists` with another openquery. I also added a temp table example. Let me know if those work.

Comment: That worked! I'm going to get busy creating a new part through our ERP system and will follow up with you afterwards if it errors on append. Thank you soooo much man!

Comment: No worries at all @DaveHolt  happy hunting

Comment: as followup, we made a new part number and ps_comp number to correlate with it and it does update. Thanks again man I really appreciate it!